# How can I see the reason that is selected on deleting my post?

Tags: feature-request, flagging, moderation, deleting

When someone is answering a question... the community (at least some members with a minimum amount of points -I suppose-)... can "flag" our post for deletion (through the button "delete"`\footnotemark[:P]`)

The questions are:

**Question 1:**
Once one answer or a post of a user is "flagged" for any reason that is given through the procedure of "flagging" from some member... How can I see the reason of this "flag". To be more specific, by flag I mean all the actions on the button "delete" or "close", or "flag" that doesn't leave an automated or manual comment under the answer/question and I am asking because I found accidentally that an [answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/477724/120578) is "flagged for deletion" but never got a notification, neither can see now the selected reason.

**Question 2:**

In my opinion, any member of the community (independent of its points) should get a notification when a post/answer is flagged and I don't mean to have access to the nickname of the one that flagged it, but at least to have access to the reason of this flag. Should we add it as a feature request?

`\footnotetext[:P]{`To be honest I don't really know the difference between the buttons "flag" and "delete" or "close" under an answer or a post and I suppose that the "flag" is just a supperset of the others.`}`

Comment: I don't think there is a possibility for normal users to see the reason why an answer was initially flagged. Maybe the flag was even automatically by a rather stupid algorithm that flags for things like length of an answer or "code only answers".

Comment: @samcarter ... thanks you. But for future readers I don't really care about the specific post... Just wondering if users should (at least) notified (I don't remember to get a notification)... and if we should, generally in stackexchage require such a feature (that could possibly hide the nickname of the user that flagged -if such a reason- but would make possible for the OP at least to learn the reason). Thank you for your comment!

Comment: I'd be much in favour of getting notifications if something happens with ones post. Unfortunately the Stackexchange philosophy is to only notify about positive things. You get notified about upvotes/new comments/answers and such, but not if a post is closed or deleted, not for downvotes etc.

Comment: Unlike close votes, delete votes never need a reason. Users can flag an answer as "Not an Answer" or "Very Low Quality" which will put the answer into the Low-Quality Review Queue. But inside the queue, reviewers are allowed to (recommend) delete without any additional comments. Also, [10k+ rep users](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can delete closed questions while [20+ rep users](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) can also delete negatively-scored answers, again, without stating any reasons.

Comment: Thanks for all this information @AndrewT.... Really useful...

Answer (score 1):

On posts for example (since your question's title implies you're inquiring about posts and not comments deletion) you can see the reason behind a deletion at the bottom of the question, like in [this example of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399696/inside-a-minipage-centering-or-flushing-environments-disables-color-command-is).

Comment: I am asking if it is possible to see the reason that is selected for my post to be deleted... Not the reason that is already deleted and even more just "closed"... All the question is about the "flagging" procedure and not already closed  posts (that aren't even deleted)... But thanks for your time...